# Не находит PyQt5 в virtualenv на centos 6

Tags: python, centos, pyqt5, pyqt, virtualenv

Ставлю на сервере (centos 6) в виртуальном окружении (virtualenv) PyQt5: `pip install pyqt5`. Пытаюсь что-нибудь написать с использованием его. На первой же строке `from PyQt5.Qt import Qt` падает ошибка `ImportError: cannot import name 'Qt'`. Вызываю просто `python generate.py` (питон третий конечно). В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А не поможет ли вот что: pip install --upgrade virtualenv

Comment: @Anton не, чет не помогло. Да и причем тут вообще это? Какая разница какая версия у пакета virtualenv? Он стоит в системе. Ставил недавно...

Comment: Попробуйте `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt`

Comment: @prusanov хмм, ошибка поменялась "ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found".

Comment: @DarkByte, просто вроде где-то нашёл, что обновление virtualenv помогло. Правда, там какой-то другой пакет был, не pyqt5. Жаль, что не сработало

Comment: А вот тут вроде пишут, что на Centos 6 glibc старый (может, похожая ситуация и с pyqt5?): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3127

Comment: Проверьте точную версию PyQt5: `from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR`. Ошибка, кажется, где-то на пересечении проблем с версиями библиотек. Ещё по версиям PyQt: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Getting%20the%20version%20numbers%20of%20Qt%2C%20SIP%20and%20PyQt

Comment: @Anton да я видел, но не понял как решили или нет. Как его обновить то?

Comment: @prusanov не думаю что проблема в версиях библиотеки... И да, на эту строку вылетает та же ошибка про GLIBC.

Comment: От версии к версии могли поменяться пространства имён, поэтому и интересуюсь версией.

Comment: К сожалению, проверить не могу, с CentOS я плохо знаком, но вот про обновление glibc на нём вроде тут отвечали: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299665

Comment: А в репах PyQt5 нет? или установить системный почему-то не хочется?

Comment: @Anton поставил наконец эту либу по инструкции. Теперь новые проблемы посыпались... Теперь когда я пытаюсь запустить свой скрипт, да хоть даже просто `python --version` мне пишет "python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

Comment: @Fat-Zer не знаю не пробовал. А зачем? Это же сервер. Он без GUI. Мне не нужен там Qt. Мне он нужен для генерации изображений только. Вообще обычно с pip проще что-то ставить чем рыться в старых системных репах.

Comment: А теперь похоже на то, что в LD_LIBRARY_PATH нет папки, в которой этот libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0 лежит

Comment: @Anton а с чего бы ему там быть? Там в конце инструкции была команда `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib`. Очевидно что в этой папке нету питона. Туда же как раз эта либа ставилась. Откуда ему там взяться?

Comment: Я бы просто предположил, что это уже другая проблема, не связанная с glibc. Может быть, стоит попробовать дополнить LD_LIBRARY_PATH? В противном случае, я уж не знаю, в чём дело может быть и что делать. Вообще, прошу прощения, может, что не так советую, не очень силён в Linux.

Comment: @DarkByte зато Qt'шные библиотеки будут точно с подходящей версией glibc собраны... я не настаиваю, что это единственно правильный вариант... скорее дело вкуса...

Comment: @Anton а вот, я понял... Последняя ошибка была связана с тем что такая переменная уже была до этого. Мне надо было написать вот так: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/glibc-2.14/lib`. Теперь та ошибка пропала, но появилась предыдущая "ImportError: /opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found". Ну точнее не совсем. Там писал про 2.14, а тут про 2.16. Даже не знаю что дальше делать... Очень надо PyQt чтоб заработал!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы с компиляцией библиотек, необходимых для работы Qt не возиться на CentOS, можно [через `conda` поставить](https://conda.io/miniconda.html): `conda install pyqt`.

Пример, который ставит miniconda сборку в centos:6 docker контейнер, создаёт отдельное окружение (pyqt5) и ставит в него pyqt пакет (по умолчанию версия):

```
$ docker run -it --rm centos:6
# mkdir miniconda && cd miniconda
# curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
# export PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
# python -V  # -> Python 3.6
# conda create -n pyqt5
# conda install -n pyqt5 pyqt
# source activate pyqt5
# python -c 'from PyQt5.Qt import Qt'
```

Comment: Ни разу не работал с conda. Чем он вообще отличается от virtualenv? И почему вы думаете что с ним будет лучше? А докера я вообще боюсь как огня... Не рискну наверное с ним связываться. Слишком сложно.

Comment: @DarkByte: 1- `docker` я использовал, чтобы продемонстрировать поведение на чистой CentOS системе (вы в вопросе указали, что на CentOS у вас сервер). Если вам docker не нужен, можно не использовать. 2- conda позволяет изолировать пакеты на разных языках написанные (в случае с Qt это C++), а не только на чистом Питоне как в случае с virtualenv (в этом случае вам самостоятельно Qt ставить придётся). Установка пакетов это задача со многими измерениями, поэтому практически все случаи являются крайними, всё на границе. В разных случаях самые разные варианты могут быть. Я показал один из рабочих